# Difference between List<T> and LinkedList<T>

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

We use List whenever we need a list. I notice now that there is a LinkedList.

I was wondering what was the difference between these 2, and when you should use one over the other.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Well, `List<T>` is basically backed by an array which is usually bigger than the current number of items. The elements are put in an array, and a new array is created when the old one runs out of space. This is fast for access by index, but slow at removing or inserting elements within the list or at the start. Adding/removing entries at the end of the list is reasonably cheap.

`LinkedList<T>` is a doubly-linked list - each node knows its previous entry and its next one. This is fast for inserting after/before a particular node (or the head/tail), but slow at access by index.

`LinkedList<T>` will *usually* take more memory than `List<T>` because it needs space for all those next/previous references - and the data will probably have less locality of reference, as each node is a separate object. On the other hand, a `List<T>` *can* have a backing array which is much larger than its current needs.

Comment: is it true LinkedList<T> holds more values than List<T>

Comment: @Shrivallabh: What do you mean by "holds more values"? That will depend on the context, version of the CLR you're using etc. Unless you're planning on storing a *huge* number of elements, it's very unlikely to be relevant.

Comment: I have application where i need to read huge text files and the ID in each line i have to store so asking LinkedList<T> is better or List<T>

Comment: @Shrivallabh: How big is "huge"? How many lines? Bear in mind that `List<T>` may be more *efficient* in memory use - especially if you know the eventual number of entries ahead of time.

Comment: I don't know the count, the file is around 20 to 40 GB and every line has ID.

Answer (score 13):

A `List<T>` is actually an array, meaning that its `Add` operation is O(1) at the end and O(n) at the front, but you can index into it in O(1). A `LinkedList<T>` is, as it says, a linked list. Since it's doubly-linked, you can add items to the front or back in O(1) but indexing into it is O(n).

Comment: Not sure where you get Add being O(log n) - I'd expect it to be amortized constant time.

Comment: Jon: You're probably right. I guess I was trying to do some averaging between O(1) at the end and O(n) at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

In almost all scenarios a List is going to outperform a LinkedList. Real world results often differ with Big O Complexity Theory.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an anwser. You don't anwser an important part of the question, you don't explain the difference between these two types. Plus, you don't explain why and when one is better than the other. That's why people downvote you.